# Is there a built-in method for Many-to-many relationships with Flask, SQLAlchemy, & WTForms

Tags: python, flask, flask-sqlalchemy, flask-wtforms

I'm using flask, WTForms, & SQLAlchemy to edit the database via a webpage. I have a table for a many-to-many relationship between elements and tasks. The model for this table is this:

```
class tasks_elements(db.Model):
    id = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key=True)
    tasks_id = db.Column(db.Integer(), db.ForeignKey('tasks.id'))
    elements_id = db.Column(db.Integer(), db.ForeignKey('elements.id'))
```

On the Task page I use this to pull the relationships for a particular task:

```
taskellist = tasks_elements.query.filter_by(tasks_id=Id)
```

There is a multi-checkbox on the form where users put a checkbox beside elements they want associated with a task. I need this list to reflect the associations and for items to be selectable and removable. I populate the currently selected elements before adding them to the form like so:

```
thisItem = tasks.query.filter_by(id=Id).first()
ellist = elements.query.with_entities(elements.id, elements.description, elements.host).order_by(elements.description)
thisItem.elCheck = []
for check in taskellist:
    for el in ellist:
        if el.id == check.elements_id:
            thisItem.elCheck.append(el.id)
```

I then check the form once submitted and add or delete as required:

```
    for i in form.elCheck.data:
        p = 0
        for q in taskellist:
            if i == q.elements_id:
                p += 1
        if p == 0:
            newTaskEl = tasks_elements(tasks_id=Id, elements_id=i)
            db.session.add(newTaskEl)
    for o in taskellist:
        a = 0
        for w in form.elCheck.data:
            if o.elements_id == w:
                a += 1
        if a == 0:
            db.session.delete(o)
```

This works as intended, but it seems terribly inefficient and I feel like I'm missing something that should make this more concise, like I'm opening the can from the wrong end.

**Question:** is this the correct way of doing this for many to many relationships, or is there a better way?